# return data of a field in store in array

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, extjs4

This might be a question of pure javascript but somehow I cant get this right. I am working on extjs4.2 using sencha architect. I have a json response sent from server as

```
{
    "data": [{
        "ExamID": 1,
        "ExamName": "Semester-1",
        "MaxMarks": 100
    }, {
        "ExamID": 4,
        "ExamName": "Test-1",
        "MaxMarks": 10
    }, {
        "ExamID": 5,
        "ExamName": "Test-2",
        "MaxMarks": 10
    }]
}
```

what I am looking for is to reconfigure grid using the data of "ExamName" only. So "ExamName" shall be passed as array in reconfigure() function.

I am unable to get "ExamName" in array form. Your help is highly appreciated

```
       var gridStore = Ext.data.StoreManager.get('ClassSemesterStore');

var g = gridStore.load( {params : {ClassID: ClassData }});

var data = g.data;

var length = data.getCount();

var examName = [];
for(var i = 0; i < length; i++){
  examName.push(data[i]['ExamName']);
}
```

it says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ExamName' of undefined"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store's `data` in not an array. It's a Mixed Collection I think. So either use the following:

```
var examName = [];
for(var i = 0; i < length; i++){
   examName.push(data.items[i].data['ExamName']);
}
```

or better yet get the information from your source like the people suggested.

Another good alternative is [Store's collect](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-collect).
You can do sth like:

```
gridStore.collect('ExamName')
```

Comment: Hi adaskos I have tried answering it above. However, I am getting an error-Excerpt gives array of previously selected record not the current record. I have also tried

Store.loadData([],false); 
to clear all the loaded data of store before loading it again.

Comment: How and when do you reconfigure your grid's store? Could it be that you have a reference to an earlier instance of the store? You need to provide more of your code.

Comment: There are two grids side by side with different stores configured. I am using grid select listener on first grid. 

When a grid row is selected it gives a 'ClassID'.
var Grid = this.getSemGrid();
var Store = Grid.getStore();     // your grid's store
var ClassData = record.get('ClassID');
console.log(ClassData);

This 'ClassID is used as Param while loading second store.
var g = Store.load( {params : {ClassID: ClassData }});

Once the store is loaded, I am getting all loaded records
var selected = g.data.item;

Then pushing all the values of one field of all records in an array..

Comment: I am feeling that it has to do with asynchronous nature of store loading... Store is loading later and our next line of code
var selected = g.data.item;
is getting executed earlier

Comment: Very much possible. `Load` function takes a callback. Try that. Or alternatively, load the data using an `Ext.Ajax` call and then use `loadData`/`loadRawData` or `reconfigure`. Those are synchronous.

Comment: unable to write it with my current code process. can u pls help

Comment: Did you try encapsulating all your code after the `load` using a `callback` function? Do this: `var g = gridStore.load( {params : {ClassID: ClassData }}, function() { /*all your code goes here....*/ } );`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55650/discussion-between-user2677125-and-adaskos).

Comment: Correct answer marked as @adaskos helped in finding right answer n chat. Thanks a lot man

Answer (score 1):

I think if I understand you correctly, you're trying to have examName be a new array with it's contents being each ExamName in your response data? If so, this should work.

```
var data = {"data":[{"ExamID":1,"ExamName":"Semester-1","MaxMarks":100},{"ExamID":4,"ExamName":"Test-1","MaxMarks":10},{"ExamID":5,"ExamName":"Test-2","MaxMarks":10}]}

var examName = [];
for(var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++){
  examName.push(data.data[i]['ExamName']);
}
```

now examName is an Array with "Semester-1", "Test-1", and "Test-2"

Comment: Or, avoiding the index-based loop: `var examName = data.reduce( function(acc,next) { acc.push( next.ExamName ); return acc }, [] );`

Comment: Very cool/interesting. What are the benefits to doing it that(not index based) way?

Comment: Thanks Tyler but this is not getting the requisite response var g = gridStore.load( {params : {ClassID: ClassData }}); This is a store associated with grid which s loading and I need to get the data of the entire store. Once I get the data of loaded store, then I need to get the field 'ExamID' and then put it into array

Comment: Added an edit but it says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ExamName' of undefined"

Comment: @TylerMcGinnis - It's a bit a matter of taste: I find the functional array operations (like `reduce`, `filter`, `every`, `some`, `forEach`etc.) more readable than the index-based. Also, it is claimed that they are more performant (see e.g. Tip 4 in http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/quick/#toc-javascript )

Answer (score 0):

The error was because of asynchronous nature of store loading:

```
var g = Store.load({
                    params : {ClassID: ClassData },
                   callback : function(records, operation, success){
                    var Excerpt = []; // start with empty array
                    Ext.each(records, function(item) {
                        // add the fields that you want to include
                        var Obj = {
                            third_field: item.get('ExamName')
                        };
                        Excerpt.push(Obj); // push this to the array
                    }, this);

                    console.log(Excerpt);
                   }
});
```